how to move a button to the right of the screen using HTML/CSS
Hello Im new to HTML and Im struggling to move a button to the far right of my screen. here's the a picture of where I want the button should be

As you can see above I want to put the button on just above the table and align with the right of the table.
I have tried using margin-left in css but iI had to put 800px and I don't think its the best way. I also tried float: right but the button is moving the table as well.
Here is my HTML and CSS code:
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css"
        integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}">
    <title>Inventory | Master Kategori</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div class="bg-white" id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-heading text-center py-4 primary-text fs-2 fw-bold text-uppercase border-bottom">
                <i></i>INVENTORY SYSTEM
            </div>
            <div class="list-group list-group-flush my-2">
                <a href="/"
                    class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text dashboard-button fw-bold"
                    style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">
                    <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Dashboard
                </a>
                <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold">
                    <a href="mastercustomer" style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-circle me-2"></i>Master
                    </a>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush my-1" style="margin-left: 15px;">
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold"
                            style="padding: 9px">
                            <a href="mastercustomer" style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">Master Customer</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold"
                            style="padding: 9px">
                            <a href="mastersupplier" style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">Master Supplier</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold"
                            style="padding: 9px">
                            <a href="masterkategori" style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">Master Kategori</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold">
                    <a href="stok
                    " style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">
                        <i class="fas fa-box me-2"></i>Storage
                    </a>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush my-1" style="margin-left: 15px;">
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold"
                            style="padding: 9px">
                            <a href="stok
                            "
                                style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">Stok</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold"
                            style="padding: 9px">
                            <a href="list" style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">List</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold"
                            style="padding: 9px">
                            <a href="list" style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">List</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <h1 class="fs-3 m-4">Master Kategori</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper-wrapper">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <form action="/addkategori">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus" style="font-size: x-large"></i> <span style="padding-left: 5px">Add Kategori</span></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid px-4">
                <div class="row my-5">
                    <div class="col">
                        <table class="table bg-white rounded shadow-sm  table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Kode</th>
                                    <th>Kategori</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>1</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>2</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>3</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>4</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>5</th>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Page Content -->


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</body>

</html>


And CSS
:root {
    --main-bg-color: #EFEDED;
    --main-text-color: #1570EF;
    --second-text-color: #bbbec5;
    --second-bg-color: #d1edf2;
}

.primary-text {
    color: var(--main-text-color);
}

.second-text {
    color: var(--second-text-color);
}

.secondary-bg {
    background-color: var(--second-bg-color);
}

.rounded-full {
    border-radius: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left,
            #d4d4d4,
            #dedede,
            #ececec,
            #f5f5f5);
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin-left: -15rem;
    transition: margin 0.25s ease-out;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
    padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
    width: 15rem;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .list-group-item:hover, #sidebar-wrapper .list-group-item:hover a {
    color: #1570EF !important;
}


#page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 100vw;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.wrapper .btn {
    height: 50px;
    background: #18C4FA;
    margin-top: 30px;  
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
  }


.list-group-item {
    border: none;
    padding: 20px 30px;
}

.list-group-item.active {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: var(--main-text-color);
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
}

.active-button {
    color: blue !important; /* Change the text color to blue */
}


@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #sidebar-wrapper {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    #page-content-wrapper {
        min-width: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        margin-left: -15rem;
    }
}

I would appreciate any help I can get, thankyou

Always Use clear:both with float for better result. so use one div float:left and on other use float:right and where this div ending, use div with clear:both.

Use Flexbox
.btn-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  gap: 1rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}



    :root {
        --main-bg-color: #EFEDED;
        --main-text-color: #1570EF;
        --second-text-color: #bbbec5;
        --second-bg-color: #d1edf2;
    }

    .primary-text {
        color: var(--main-text-color);
    }

    .second-text {
        color: var(--second-text-color);
    }

    .secondary-bg {
        background-color: var(--second-bg-color);
    }

    .rounded-full {
        border-radius: 100%;
    }

    #wrapper {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to left,
                #d4d4d4,
                #dedede,
                #ececec,
                #f5f5f5);
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        min-height: 100vh;
        margin-left: -15rem;
        transition: margin 0.25s ease-out;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
        padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
        font-size: 1.2rem;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
        width: 15rem;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper .list-group-item:hover, #sidebar-wrapper .list-group-item:hover a {
        color: #1570EF !important;
    }


    #page-content-wrapper {
        min-width: 100vw;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

    .wrapper .btn {
        height: 50px;
        background: #18C4FA;
        margin-top: 30px;  
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: 600;
      }


    .list-group-item {
        border: none;
        padding: 20px 30px;
    }

    .list-group-item.active {
        background-color: transparent;
        color: var(--main-text-color);
        font-weight: bold;
        border: none;
    }

    .active-button {
        color: blue !important; /* Change the text color to blue */
    }


    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        #sidebar-wrapper {
            margin-left: 0;
        }

        #page-content-wrapper {
            min-width: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
            margin-left: -15rem;
        }
    }

    .btn-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      gap: .5rem;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css"
            integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA=="
            crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}">
        <title>Inventory | Master Kategori</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <div class="bg-white" id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <div class="sidebar-heading text-center py-4 primary-text fs-2 fw-bold text-uppercase border-bottom">
                    <i></i>INVENTORY SYSTEM
                </div>
                <div class="list-group list-group-flush my-2">
                    <a href="/"
                        class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text dashboard-button fw-bold"
                        style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">
                        <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Dashboard
                    </a>
                    <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold">
                        <a href="mastercustomer" style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">
                            <i class="fas fa-user-circle me-2"></i>Master
                        </a>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush my-1" style="margin-left: 15px;">
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold"
                                style="padding: 9px">
                                <a href="mastercustomer" style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">Master Customer</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold"
                                style="padding: 9px">
                                <a href="mastersupplier" style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">Master Supplier</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold"
                                style="padding: 9px">
                                <a href="masterkategori" style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">Master Kategori</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold">
                        <a href="stok
                        " style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">
                            <i class="fas fa-box me-2"></i>Storage
                        </a>
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush my-1" style="margin-left: 15px;">
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold"
                                style="padding: 9px">
                                <a href="stok
                                "
                                    style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">Stok</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold"
                                style="padding: 9px">
                                <a href="list" style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">List</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-transparent second-text fw-bold"
                                style="padding: 9px">
                                <a href="list" style="text-decoration: none; color: gray;">List</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



            <!-- Page Content -->
            <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                    <h1 class="fs-3 m-4 mb-0">Master Kategori</h1>
                </div>
                
                <div class="container-fluid px-4">
                    <div class="btn-wrapper wrapper">
                        <form action="/addkategori">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus" style="font-size: x-large"></i> <span style="padding-left: 5px">Add Kategori</span></button>
                        </form>
                        <button type="button" class="btn">Add</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row mb-5 mt-2">
                        <div class="col">
                            <table class="table bg-white rounded shadow-sm  table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>#</th>
                                        <th>Kode</th>
                                        <th>Kategori</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>1</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>2</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>3</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>4</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>5</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Page Content -->


        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>




thankyou sir it worked! but what if i want to add another button beside it with different color?

Just add the 'gap' property to the '.btn-wrapper' class and place buttons inside it. If there's not enough horizontal space for two buttons, they'll automatically stack vertically due to the 'flex-wrap: wrap;' property. I've updated the code snippet.
